# What is the email of Satoshi Nakamoto?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

I know the Satoshi Nakamoto profile: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=3 and his public key: http://forum.bitcoin.org/Satoshi_Nakamoto.asc

And I know maybe Satoshi is not a real person, but a pseudonymous of a group of people.

But there is a way to send a message to Satoshi? Is there a public email? Any kind of contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email he used was satoshin@gmx.com.

Comment: But do you know if it still works? Thanks.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli I seriously doubt that he still checks it. Don't know if it still works.

Comment: WARNING: do not send any email to this address, it was compromised: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=775174.0

Answer (score 5):

He used [satoshin@gmx.com (from original Bitcoin whitepaper)](https://archive.org/details/BitcoinAPeer-to-PeerElectronicCashSystem) and [satoshi@vistomail.com (from email logs)](http://blog.dustintrammell.com/2013/11/26/i-am-not-satoshi/). gmx.com is a free email service that may or may not have had location based restrictions on registration at the time. vistomail.com is an email service from anonymousspeech, the domain registrar proxy he used to register bitcoin.org.